# Find the missing ids that are in a specific pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am looking for a way to find the missing ids in a range of cells. The thing is, there is a pattern and not a pure number - it is `PW140000023`. The other thing that might complicate this search is there are duplicate ids, which is ok. I found this expression:

```
SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ROW(A1:A30),A1:A30,0)),ROW(A1:A30)),ROW(A1))
```

Though it does not yield any results. How can I modify this to my needs?

Example of missing ids:

```
PW140000023
PW140000023
PW140000025  'missing PW140000024
PW140000026
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "find missing ids" - How do you know which IDs are meant to be there? Your question and sample formula don't make much sense to me as-is.

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of the data wherein there is a "missing id"?

Comment: @JohnBustos, there are supposed to be sequential, with some duplicates ids as well

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with a formula. It would be easy to loop through the cells in vba and parse the data and check to see if they are sequential or duplicate.

Comment: @Kevin, I am ok with a macro

Comment: When you say that the pattern "is PW140000023" - does that mean that every single one of your entries begins with the string "PW14" and is followed by seven digits?

Comment: @XORLX, that is correct, but the beginning will change for diff files - i figure i can change something simple though

Comment: If they start with a set number of non-numeric characters and then all's numeric, you could then do stuff based upon that bit of logic...

Comment: And can you give a lower and upper bound to the numerical part, or do we potentially have to check for just under 10 million possibilities from 0000001 to 9999999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data starts in A1, enter this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(MID(A2,3,99)-MID(A1,3,99)>2,"missing PW"&MID(A1,3,99)+1&" - PW"&MID(A2,3,99)-1,
    IF(MID(A2,3,99)-MID(A1,3,99)>1,"missing PW"&MID(A1,3,99)+1,"")
 )
```

Output:

[image]

That was a bit of a brute force solution.

Here's a shorter solution by 32 characters, but it may be a bit confusing:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(
  "missing PW"&MID(A1,3,99)+1&REPT(" ",99)&"-PW"&MID(A2,3,99)-1,
  MAX(0,(MID(A2,3,99)-MID(A1,3,99)-1))*99)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, that will do just fine.

Comment: Great.  I've added another, shorter solution.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I can work with this format, what would be a cherry on the top is to just make an array of the missing and add them to a separate column - that maybe a for new question

Comment: That would be a good new question, and you may get a good VBA solution.  (I'm a JavaScript guy, myself.)  That would be quite a challenge to do using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Without using VBA, you could add a formula in a new column next to each id. Assuming your ID's are column A starting in Row 1, the following will show FALSE on rows that come after a missing ID:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "PW" & RIGHT(A1, 9)-1)>0
```

You would add that to B1 and then copy down the column.

Comment: How do I get just a list of the missing numbers rather than TRUE/FALSE